# Why am I getting a empty or null print when converting bool to char

Tags: java

So I'm converting a bool to a int then to a char using branch-less programming. But when ran I'm getting an empty print out. I'm converting it so if a bool is False it generates an O but if True and X.

```
int Turn = (boolturn) ? 1:0 * 9 + 79;
char playerchr = (char)Turn;
System.out.println(playerchr);
```

Comment: How do you convert from `boolean` to `int`?

Comment: Wups the code snippet was formated wrong

Comment: Since you have to use a conditional anyway, why not just convert to char directly, using char literals? Why should someone who reads your code have to *think about* what is special about the numbers 79 and 9? Hint: the person who reads your code most often is *you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets where they're needed: `int Turn = (boolturn ? 1 : 0) * 9 + 79;`

---

Also, why not just `char playerchr = boolturn ? 'X' : 'O'` (piggybacking on @StephenC's answer)? It's not less "branchless" than the former variant (the ternary operator `?:` is still a kind of branching, though).

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Vershin spotted, you made a mistake with the operator precedence.  The `*` operator has a higher precedence than the conditional operator, so you need to use parentheses to express what you are apparently trying to do here.

---

But seriously, the sane way to write that code in Java is:

```
char playerchr = (boolturn) ? 'O' : 'X';
```

And note that should be `turn` not `Turn`, and `boolTurn` not `boolturn`, and `playerChar` not `playerchr`.

Java code should be *written* to be readable ... if you want other people to be able to read it.  (Or even if you want to be able to read it yourself in a few weeks time!)